# angular google maps show a loader before the map is loaded

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

I'm using this good module:
http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps

and I'm wondering how can show a loader before
the map is loaded/showed
I've tried simply (in the view)

```
ng-if="map"
```

but it doesn't work.
Can anyone give en hint, please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this with a promise, using [`isReady`](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api) and `ng-show`, `ng-hide`:

Controller:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, uiGmapIsReady) {

    $scope.map = { center: { latitude: 45, longitude: -73 }, zoom: 8 };

    uiGmapIsReady.promise(1).then(function() {
      $scope.mapLoaded = true;
    });

  });
```

View:

```
<p ng-hide='mapLoaded'>loading...</p>

<ui-gmap-google-map ng-show='mapLoaded' center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom'></ui-gmap-google-map
```